# Build Entity Framework query from a list of input value pairs to form OR clauses

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a list of `ListItem` objects:

```
var items = new List<ListItem> 
    { 
        new ListItem{ Code = "X", Type = ItemTypes.Type1},
        new ListItem{ Code = "Y", Type = ItemTypes.Type1},
        new ListItem{ Code = "Z", Type = ItemTypes.Type2},
        new ListItem{ Code = "Z", Type = ItemTypes.Type2},
    };
```

And I have a table (EF model) of `TableItem` objects:

```
public class TableItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public ItemTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

My question is how can I query all `TableItem` records matching the same code/type in the list items using Entity Framework, like

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableItems 
WHERE 
    (Type = items[0].Type AND Code = items[0].Code AND Active=true) OR
    (Type = items[1].Type AND Code = items[1].Code AND Active=true) OR
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use expressions:

```
Expression<Func<TableItem, bool>> query = de => false;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Expression<Func<TableItem, bool>> exp = de => de.Code == item.Code && de.Type == item.Type && de.Active == true;
    query = Expression.Lambda<Func<TableItem, bool>>(
        Expression.OrElse(query.Body,
        Expression.Invoke(exp, query.Parameters.Cast<Expression>())), query.Parameters);
}

var res = await applicationDbContext.TableItems.Where(query).ToListAsync();
```

[Predicate Builder](https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).
This link has a nice extension that you could use instead of typing the code above.

Comment: This is the answer, Thanks @hmz

Answer (score -1):

May be it just help

```
var listCodes = items.Select(x => x.Code).ToList(); 
var listTypes = items.Select(x => x.Type).ToList();
var result = DbContext.TableItems.Where(x => listCodes.Contains(x.Code) && listType.Contains(x.Type) && x.Active == true);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I will get any record with code in my codes and separately type is in my types, while I need to make sure that both code and type pair match in the same record.
I could get the incorrect TableItem with Code=X and Type=Type2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).